# Миграция в существующей БД EFCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

В проекте EF (5.0.7) Core создает модели по уже существующей базе данных с помощью команды scaffold-dbcontext, в классе, представляющим одну из моделей, добавляется новое свойство для создания соответствующего столбца, выполняется создания миграции и обновление базы данных командой update-database, но во время обновления БД возникает исключение, что в БД уже существует объект с данным именем(имя одной из модели, представляющей таблицу), как это исправить и есть ли вообще способ миграции в уже существующей БД?

```
public partial class m1 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Table1",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                SomeColumn1 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                SomeColumn2 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Table1", x => x.Id);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Table1");
    }
}

[DbContext(typeof(SomeDBContext))]
[Migration("20220528102543_m1")]
partial class m1
{
    protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "Cyrillic_General_CI_AS")
            .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "5.0.7")
            .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

        modelBuilder.Entity("EFLearn.Table1", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int")
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                b.Property<string>("SomeColumn1")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("SomeColumn2")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.ToTable("Table1");
            });
    }
}
```

SomeColumn2-свойство, которое добавляется

[image: Само исключение:]

Comment: _есть ли вообще способ миграции в уже существующей БД?_ - Миграции - это и есть способ внесения изменений в существующую БД.

Comment: Меньше слов, больше кода. Покажите сгенерированный файл миграции после добавления свойства.

Comment: И хотелось бы знать версию EF, конкретную СУБД и прочее.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov EF версии 5.0.7 СУБД MSSQL Server. Вопрос обновил